# I have a component which is receiving data from the store. How can I update the data received and rerender the component on change

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, javascript-objects

I have a store which gives me array of password objects
For Example :

```js
const passwords = [{
    id: 'hjgkjhkjl',
    password: 'jhckjdhf',
    createdAt: 'jan 3rd, 2019'
  },
  {
    id: 'uygkjhkj',
    password: 'kdjhfkjdhf',
    createdAt: 'jan 3rd, 2019'
  }
]
```

I can access this passwords in my component as this.props.passwords

I am trying to populate them on UI as a List with  button(Update / Confirm) - I am toggling between them using a component level state

Since it is a component level state if I click on one button all the buttons are getting changed

Here is my code

```js
class Passwords extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      disabled: false

    }
    this.handleUpdate = this.handleUpdate.bind(this)
  }

  handleUpdate(element) {
    // this.context.executeAction(removePassword, element.createdAt)
    // this.context.executeAction(fetchPasswords)
    this.setState({
      disabled: !this.state.disabled,
    })
  }

  render() {

    const data = [
      {
        password: "passwordone",
        createdAt: "Jan 2, 2019"
      },
      {
        password: "passwordtwo",
        createdAt: "Jan 2, 2019"
      }
    ];

    return (
      <div>
        {data.map((element) => {
          return (
            <div>
              <input value={element.password} disabled={!this.state.disabled}/>
              <span style={{marginLeft: "15px"}}> {element.createdAt} </span>
              <span style={{marginLeft: "15px"}}>
                <button onClick={() => this.handleUpdate(element)}> 
                  {this.state.disabled ? "Confirm" : "Update"}
                </button> 
              </span>
            </div>
          )
        })}
      </div>
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Passwords/>, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id='root'>

</div>
```

Need a better approach to solve this

Working example is in the following [Link](https://codepen.io/punith77/pen/QzaJER?editors=1111)

id are unique for the password items - expected result update/confirm need to be toggled only for clicked button

Thanks in advance

Comment: You're never tracking which item/id you're clicking in `handleUpdate`. You're probably going to be better off encapsulating this into another component.

Comment: Thanks Worked like a charm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As sellmeadog said, you should create a parent component that will contain 2 components. Each component will have its own state, and the parent component will give each child its props. This way each button will have its own state, which means its own "disabled". In general it should look like that:

```js
class PasswordsContainer extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    const data = [
      {
        password: 'passwordone',
        createdAt: 'Jan 2, 2019',
      },

      {
        password: 'passwordtwo',
        createdAt: 'Jan 2, 2019',
      },
    ];

    this.state = {
      disabled: false,
      data: data,
    };
    this.handleUpdate = this.handleUpdate.bind(this);
  }

  handleUpdate(element) {
    // this.context.executeAction(removePassword, element.createdAt)
    // this.context.executeAction(fetchPasswords)
    this.setState({
      disabled: !this.state.disabled,
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.state.data.map(element => {
          return <Password data={element} />;
        })}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
class Password extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      disabled: false,
      data: this.props.data,
    };
    this.handleUpdate = this.handleUpdate.bind(this);
  }

  handleUpdate(element) {
    this.setState({
      disabled: !this.state.disabled,
    });
  }

  render() {
    let element = this.state.data;
    return (
      <div>
        <input value={element.password} disabled={!this.state.disabled} />
        <span
          style={{
            marginLeft: '15px',
          }}>
          {' '}
          {element.createdAt}
        </span>
        <span
          style={{
            marginLeft: '15px',
          }}>
          <button onClick={() => this.handleUpdate(element)}>
            {this.state.disabled ? 'Confirm' : 'Update'}
          </button>
        </span>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<PasswordsContainer />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id='root'>

</div>
```

*please tell me if something is unclear*

Answer (score 1):

You're having this problem because you assigned both buttons to the same value in your state. By toggling one button and updating that shared state value, it would make sense that both buttons get updated.

What you should do instead is move your buttons down into a child component, where they keep track of their own piece of state. So when you click on one button, it will only change the state for that component.